# A macro to send a email

Tags: sas, sas-macro

my code to send mail using sas data step. here trying to create a code to send mail.

```
FILENAME outbox EMAIL ("***********");
DATA _NULL_;
FILE outbox
TO=("************")
FROM=("***********")
SUBJECT=("Example of a SAS E-mail" );
/* ATTACH=(""); */
PUT " ";
PUT "Hello Boss,";
PUT " ";
PUT "Attached are the Daily Operational Reports.";
PUT " ";
PUT "rrt";
RUN;
```

Comment: Would you please reword your question? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: A macro which will send an email. using filename

Comment: Assuming your data step is working, you can just wrap that into macro, I will show it in my answer.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Your question is completely unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't tend to include email parameters in the datastep itself, but rather in fileref. I have tested the code below with my email address and it worked.

As I said in the comments, you simply need to wrap your datastep in a macro if you want it to run within macro.

You can have positional or keyword parameters. See this [source](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#macro-stmt.htm) for detailed info. I have used keyword parameters in this example. you call the macro by specifying the keyword and then the value like I showed the last line. If you don't put anything, then the keyword gets ignored.

By the way, the empty keywords result in initialised local macro variables. Let statements like ( %LET FROM=FROM="&FROM") are there to add a string "FROM=" to the beginning of "FROM" macro variable so the filename syntax would be complete. If macro variable such as "FROM" would be passed as is, it would resolve to email address that filename woudn't know what to do with.

```
   %MACRO send_email (TO=,FROM=,SUBJECT=,ATTACHMENT=,BODY=);
    %IF &TO ne %THEN
        %LET TO="&TO";

    %IF &FROM ne %THEN
        %LET FROM=FROM="&FROM";

    %IF &SUBJECT ne %THEN
        %LET SUBJECT=SUBJECT="&SUBJECT";

    %IF &ATTACHMENT ne %THEN
        %LET ATTACHMENT=ATTACHMENT="&ATTACHMENT";

    %IF &BODY ne %THEN
        %LET BODY="&BODY";
    FILENAME outbox EMAIL &TO &FROM &SUBJECT &ATTACHMENT;

    DATA _NULL_;
        FILE outbox;
        PUT &BODY;
    RUN;

%MEND;

%send_email(email=example@example.com);
```

Comment: I have changed my answer to show how you can user keyword parameters for a macro. I don't know about the error for cipher. There were double quotes used incorrectly in my last example. That could have caused the error, or may be the way you are connecting to smtp server which would be in your config potentially.

Comment: Googling "Unable to create cipher" leads to this blog post from Chris, where the issue is discussed in the comments.  Seems it's potentially related to SAS/secure... http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/07/31/gmail-from-sas-program/

Comment: @ quentin @Vasoliji i read d blog but now am having this error->  ERROR: Email host FILENAME not found.
& why have you used multiple = = in the % let statment?

Comment: Hello Peeyush, it is not a double equal sign. In this example ( FROM=FROM="&FROM"), first "from" is the name of macro variable that I am assigning the value of "FROM=" as well as value of "&FROM" parameter. About your email host problem, was your original data step working? Can you check if  EMAILHOST= System Option is set correctly in your instance?

Comment: By the way, to check EMAILHOST option, you should run this code: PROC OPTIONS option=EMAILHOST; RUN; Check you log, you must see a value to your emailhost option, something like smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Peeyush,

Try the code sample below. Make sure to enter your SMTP email host details and the email addresses to and from. You can make the email addresses macro variables if you want additional automation:

```
%macro emailM;
OPTIONS emailsys = SMTP emailhost = Youremail.Host.net emailport= 25;
FILENAME Mailbox EMAIL 'You@something.com';
attach=("\\somewhere\something\File.xls");
DATA _NULL_;
FILE MailBox TO=("somebody@something.com" "somebody2@something.com") 
Subject="Example of a SAS E-mail";
PUT "Hello Boss,";
PUT " ";
PUT "Attached are the Daily Operational Reports.";
PUT " ";
PUT "Thank you";
RUN;
%mend emailM;

%emailM;
```